# Wirecloud marketplace install widget is not allowed

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I've correctly installed a Wirecloud instance in my own server.
 I've added a Marketplace available at this address http://130.206.81.113/FiwareMarketplace/v1.
I can retrieve the data from Marketplace correctly, and I can see all available  widgets but **I can't install anyone of them**.
The only button present on each widget is **Details**, but I need **Install** to use them in my workspace.

Can I solve this issue in any way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, WireCloud only allows you to install components from a marketplace/store if you are using the same IdM server in all the services: the marketplace, the store and WireCloud. As you want to use the global instance of the Marketplace, you should use the FIWARE Lab's KeyRock instance (`https://account.lab.fiware.org`) for authenticating users in your WireCloud instance to be able to install components from the FIWARE Lab's Marketplace.

> **NOTE**: The Marketplace GE and the Store GE are currently in support mode. The Business API Ecosystem GE is going to replace it, but it won't be released until summer 2016.